# .change() on all textboxes and textarea

Tags: jquery

```
$(':input[type=text], textarea').change(function(){
     if(($(":input[type=text]").val()!="") && $("textarea").val()!=""){
      $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
      $(":submit").removeClass("disabled");
      $(":submit").addClass("success");
     }
});
```

This function is triggered when I have entered text into 1 out of the total 2 textarea elements in my form.

But I want this function to be triggered once all of the textboxes and text area are not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be best off adding a class to your elements to identify them. Plus it would make the code more semantic:

```
<input type="text" name="Texbox1" class="elementGroup" />
<textarea name="Textarea1" class="elementGroup"></textarea>
<textarea name="Textarea2" class="elementGroup"></textarea>
```

Then in your code you can attach your event, and check to see if all three elements have a value set:

```
$('.elementGroup').change(function() {
    var valid = true;
    $('.elementGroup').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "")
            valid = false;
    });

    if (valid)
        $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled").toggleClass("disabled success");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VLKSQ/2/)

Comment: The `return false;` in the `each()` isn't preventing the actions on `$(":submit")` been performed..

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to iterate through the `inputs` and `textareas` to make sure that each is not empty

```
$('input[type=text], textarea').change(function(){
  x=0;
  $('input[type=text], textarea').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()==''){x=1;}
  });
  if(x==0){
    $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(":submit").removeClass("disabled");
    $(":submit").addClass("success");
  }
});
```

thanks for the -1 for missing the == (i'm guessing since it does exactly what the accepted answer does.)

Comment: The `return false;` in the `each()` isn't preventing the actions on `$(":submit")` been performed..

Comment: Really? Then I guess there's something I don't know about going on there. Making it a flag would probably work better I guess.